# Weird intersecting mesh on final render (w/ Boolean modifier)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I'm using a Boolean modifier set to *Exact* (Blender 2.91.0) to create a rather simple shape to merge a disk and and another half disk (see attached), and while it all looks fine in the render preview, on the final render I have this weird intersecting cluster I can only assume happens because of the Boolean mod.

[image]

I've made sure the bool object is not visible on final render but no difference. Has anyone come across this and has a fix?

(The issue seems to be gone when I change the Boolean modifier mode to *Fast*, but if anyone has tips on making it work in *Exact* mode that'd be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, there has been improvements to the boolean algorithm very recently, but you have to use an experimental version to test it (Latest 2.93) : https://builder.blender.org/download/ You can try and see if your case behaves better with it. Backup your file before use, eperimental versions can corrupt projects

Comment: Thanks so much for replying to the query! for the time being I had to use the *Fast* mode to resolve it, but will see if 2.93 resolves it without having to switch it.

Comment: Boolean operations often create messy topology and geometry which can create strange artifacts.  In your case it appears that your geometry is simple enough that it probably doesn't warrant requiring a boolean operation to create.

Comment: @PGmath that explains why I've had several issues with it (I come from 2D tools where I don't worry about topology ). I've got very little modelling skills, so tend to rely on these modifiers for these shapes. Will need to think about how to model it out so thanks! (feel free to share tips on how might model it with clean topology)